# How do I slice a word out of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

Here is my code:

```
query = "This is a good life"
=> "This is a good life"
query.slice!("is")
=> "is"
query
=> "Th is a good life"
```

What I am trying to do is to slice a fragment only if it is a single word, not a part of another word.

- Slicing `(" is ")` leaves no space between previous and following words and won't work for the first or the last word of a string.
- `("is ")` or `(" is")` do not guarantee that a fragment is not a part of a word.

Comment: How about an approach that first splits the string by whitespace characters?

Answer (score 6):

**[**Edit: Readers, please see @Stefan's comment. He is entirely correct. The lookarounds and character classes I have are unnecessary; all that's needed is `\b` on each side of "is". There's a lesson here, I think: when one wants to do something in Ruby that's fairly commonplace, like replacing a word in a text, there's probably a way to do it with the minimum of fuss and bother.**]**

If you intend to deal with the fullness of the English language, this is not a simple question. Here's an approach you might want to adapt:

```
query = "This is a good life, it is; yes, indeed it is!"

query.gsub(/(?<=\b|[;:-])is(?=\b|[.?!])/i,'')
  => "This  a good life, it ; yes, indeed it !"
```

In the regex, `(?<=\b|[;:-])`is a "positive lookbehind"; `(?=\b|[.?!])` is a "positive lookahead".

Comment: Wouldn't a word boundary work just as well? `gsub(/\bis\b/i, '')`

Comment: Considering who authored the comment above, I expect I've messed up, but let me think a moment...

Comment: Wow! Confession is not just good for the soul; it's good for rep at SO. (+30 since my edit just a few minutes ago.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` too. `gsub` if you want to replace all occurrences of " is " in the string

```
query = "This is a good life"
# => "This is a good life"
query.sub(" is ", " ")   
# => "This a good life"
query.gsub(" is ", " ") 
# => "This a good life"
```

Comment: What about "Is it?", "That it is.", "Now is\nthe time"?

Comment: i fear my code is not handling those cases. As the OP himself did not considered them, I skipped them too. I saw how you handled them. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

try with `" is"`

```
 > query = "This is a good life"
 => "This is a good life" 
 > query.slice!(" is")
 => " is" 
 > query
 => "This a good life"
```

Comment: Did you read "("is ") or (" is") do not guarantee that a fragment is not a part of a word." in the question?

Comment: Yes I read but what is the difference to use between `gsub`, `sub` or `slice` ? All follow the same method and return the same result I think

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty of this problem is about the boundary, if the word is the first or the last in the string.

```
x = "is"  # any word to slice
query = "This is a good life"
query.gsub(/(\b\s#{x}\b|^#{x}\b\s|\b\s#{x}$)/, '') # "This a good life"
x = "This"
query.gsub(/(\b\s#{x}\b|^#{x}\b\s|\b\s#{x}$)/, '') # "is a good life"
x = "life"
query.gsub(/(\b\s#{x}\b|^#{x}\b\s|\b\s#{x}$)/, '') # "This is a good"
```